# Unexpected Error while trying to replicate data

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to build a grouped barchart that shows two groups for two different situations. I am a beginner so i'm trying to replicate from examples i've seen online.

```
#create dataframe
Gene<-c("IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal")
count1<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
count2<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
count3<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
count4<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
Species<-c("0","0","1","1","2","2","3","3","4","4")
cols = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

df<-data.frame(Gene,count1,count2,count3,count4,Species)

df1  = transform(df, mean=rowMeans(df[cols]), sd=apply(df[cols],1, sd))


ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.factor(Gene), y=mean, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='black') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
```

My R code is above and below is what I would like to achieve.

[image: trying to achieve]

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are getting?

Comment: You're selecting columns 2 up to 11 from `data.frame` `df` which has only 6 columns. Try replacing `col` with `col <- 2:5`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your problem is found in the transformation that gives me error

To add mean and standard deviation to your data you can use the dplyr package and the function mutate. For calculating the mean and sd for every row you just need to add rowwise() to your pipeline

```
  Gene<-c("IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal")
count1<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
count2<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
count3<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
count4<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,69.75771,79.64783)
Species<-c("0","0","1","1","2","2","3","3","4","4")
cols = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)

df<-data.frame(Gene,count1,count2,count3,count4,Species)

df1 <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(mean=(count1+count2+count3+count4)/3, stdev = sd(c(count1, count2, count3, count4)))

ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.factor(Gene), y=mean, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='black') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-stdev, ymax=mean+stdev), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))+
  labs(title="title", x= "X axis name", y = "Y axis name")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG4Yv.jpg)

Comment: Hey could you mention the libraries you use for this. I am getting errors

Comment: Hey, if I am not forgetting anything it should be "gglpot", "dplyr", and "tidyverse", hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

It is advisable to check first where your error occurs as there is nothing wrong with your chart (ok perhaps not finished in all details but did not throw the error).

Your data preparation went wrong.
It is also wise if you want to work with a standard deviation that you actually give us data that gives us a SD value not being 0 ;)

```
Gene<-c("IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal","IMR-90","Normal")
count1<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,83.61812,78.34494,85.92033,62.75771,79.64783)
count2<-c(110,100,92.2453,87.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,65.75771,79.64783)
count3<-c(100,110,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,55.75771,70.64783)
count4<-c(100,100,92.2453,81.76718,83.326,80.61812,78.34494,85.92033,68.75771,79.64783)
Species<-c("0","0","1","1","2","2","3","3","4","4")


library(data.table)

df<- data.table(Gene, count1, count2, count3, count4, Species)
cols <- c("count1", "count2", "count3", "count4")

df1 <- df[, .(mean = rowMeans(.SD), sd = sd(.SD)), by = .(Gene, Species), .SDcols = cols]


ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.factor(Gene), y=mean, fill=Species)) +
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour='black') +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax=mean+sd), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure whether introducing another R package like `data.table` is going to be very useful for somebody who is just learning the basics in R. Why not stick with base R?

Comment: Established libraries are there for a reason, whether you start learning dplyr or data.table for data  manipulation is another debate. They are there for a reason, not for "hey see what I can do the same as base". It would have suited you to give the answer in base though instead of discussing the provided answer not using base.

Comment: OP has difficulties with some basic R operations. `data.table` introduces unnecessary complexities, obfuscating the key issue (which is that of selecting the right columns).

Comment: Fair enough in this case, honestly I always use data.table but have to admit his code actually worked just by fixing the cols. So yes in this case it was not needed to rewrite. Just a habit if you see something not working to do a solution in your own prefered way.